# why am I not getting the transform and input etc commands C# in vs code for godot?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-code, godot

I'm trying to use godot which is like in screenshot below.

[image]

I don't have access to commands such as transform, input etc. Every solution I find is for Unity and not Godot.

I tried the C# dev kit extension.
I even downloaded Unity to try some of the solutions there but none worked.

Comment: add a [mre] snippet of code that can be used to reproduce this and give us version numbers for all the things (everything you can think of that is relevant to this question. OS, VS Code, C# extensions, .NET SDK, etc.)

Comment: Are you using VSCode extensions for Godot integration?